# Upgrading Informix - Switch to Oracle, Sybase or stay with Informix?

Tags: oracle, sybase, rdbms, informix

Previously I posted a question so I could confirm our current (albeit archaic) version of Informix here:

[How do you identify Informix version on Solaris?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682154/how-do-you-identify-informix-version-on-solaris)

(Thank you Jonathan and RET for clearing that up)

We are definitely planning on upgrading but are first discussing if it would make more sense to move to Oracle or Sybase at this time. What are your opinions on this? It's my belief that while all 3 RDBMs have their own uniqueness, they must all cover the same ground essentially. So how does one go about deciding what database to use?

The big kicker is I need to know if we upgrade Informix (currently using 7.13), will we need to modify our embedded sql C programs? If not, then it makes a lot of sense to stick with Informix. Because if we went with Sybase/Oracle etc, we'd have a lot of work on our hands to update the back-end programs.

But if switching to another database can offer great return in comparison then we will still consider it. I look forward to hearing your opinions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a biassed observer (I work for IBM on Informix) - treat my comments with due caution.

If your applications are written in Informix ESQL/C, you would have to do major surgery to move them to other systems.  You would need to decide which alternative interface to use - your cross-platform choice (with C as the basic language) is ODBC, but Oracle provides the OCI and Sybase provides the TDS as alternatives.

By contrast, with Informix ESQL/C, an upgrade to the current version (Informix ClientSDK 3.50, containing ESQL/C 3.50, which *is* more recent than the ESQL/C 6.00 which you currently use) should be painless unless you've gone out of your way to write bad code.

Even simply migrating the data might be a little traumatic - not insuperably so.  In part, the complexity depends on which data types you use.  (Character strings migrate easily; date and time values less easily, for example.)  But migrating the applications would require a lot of work, as you say, unless you were extraordinarily prescient and wrote a really good data abstraction layer.

An upgrade to Informix SE 7.26 would be a no-brainer - get the software, install it, point it at your existing database.  You'd probably want to recompile your programs to use the more modern CSDK, but you could do that incrementally with care (two INFORMIXDIR values, one for the old code, one for the new).

An upgrade to Informix Dynamic Server (IDS) 11.50 would require you to export the data (DB-Export) from SE and import it (DB-Import) into IDS.  This would be very simple too, once you have IDS up and running.  Getting IDS up and running takes more effort than SE, but is not all that hard.

Clearly, my recommendation is to stay put with Informix.  The decision is yours, of course.

---

> With IDS, would we have to make code changes or just recompile?

IDS is very closely related to SE, but they are different.  IDS provides an almost strict superset of SE functionality.  The places I can think of where there are differences are primarily edge case stuff:

- SE has extra syntax to CREATE TABLE for locating C-ISAM files for the database; IDS has a wholly different set of extensions.  The basic CREATE TABLE is the same (though IDS has types that SE doesn't, such as VARCHAR), but the adornments are different.
- SE has CREATE AUDIT and DROP AUDIT and IDS does not (it has other audit facilities).
- SE has START DATABASE and ROLLFORWARD DATABASE; IDS does not (recovery and logging in IDS is different).

The main area that may cause issues is transaction management.  IDS has unlogged, logged and 'LOG MODE ANSI' database, as does SE.  In IDS, you are encouraged to use a logged database - that would be a strong recommendation.  IDS provides atomic statements in a logged database - either the statement works as a whole or it fails as a whole.  However, many SE applications are not written with transactions in mind.  There are some things you can't do when there are transactions on the database, such as open a cursor for update outside the scope of a transaction.  This is what tends to bite code migrating from SE to IDS.  Also, you cannot lock a table except in a transaction, and you cannot unlock a table except by COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

How much of a problem this will be depends on what you were using in SE and how the programs were designed (if they were designed rather than thrown together).  An IDS unlogged database and an SE unlogged database are very close - and you could migrate from one to the other.  But IDS can do things (like replication) only when the databases are logged, and you should aim to be using logged databases.

However, the migration to CSDK 3.50 should be just a recompile unless you've managed to do some really excruciatingly awful things.

Comment: Jonathan, I really appreciate your detailed feedback on this. We do realize that if we migrate to Oracle from Informix, we have a rather large project on our hands. We currently have over 1000 C programs with embedded sql. With IDS, would we have to make code changes or just recompile?

Comment: Jonathan, again thank you for the detailed reply. While our C code w/ embedded sql is not very complicated - it was written *years* ago and I would say it's more "thrown together" for sure. Our DBA team has met w/ IBM and we still need to meet w/ Oracle, to be fully able to evaluate our choices.

Answer (score 4):

Rumours of Informix's demise are greatly exaggerated.

With the investment in embedded code that you have, any apparent sticker price cost saving to be had from switching to brand O or brand S would very quickly disappear in redevelopment costs. That's just a fact of life: I've seen projects burn $100K+ on redevelopment to save $20K p.a. in licensing. That's not money well spent.

You would want to be very, very sure that the switch of RDBMS was going to offer something you really couldn't achieve sticking with what you have. Because the risk (from bitter experience - I fought against it long and hard) is that you could spend a fortune in dollars and time just running on the spot, if not going backwards.

If you're going to step back and look at your problem holistically, I think you would be far better off evaluating the possibilities of newer, loosely coupled, database-agnostic architectures than swapping one embedded model for another. This would provide you much greater flexibility down the track.

Hope that helps.

Comment: RET, thank you for the detailed feedback. This is difficult for us to ascertain - the cost of staying w/ Informix (for us that includes licensing plus db training) versus the cost of going to Oracle (we already have license and db admin expertise). So we definitely have some evaluating ahead of us.

Comment: Just to expand on the above, the cost of migrating to Oracle would include the development time and resources to migrate embedded sql applications.

Comment: @KNewton: So, out of curiosity, did you stick with informix or move to another db?.. if you moved, did it require a major effort to rewrite code?

Answer (score 1):

We have been supporting Informix DB for years using GeneXus.  Informix is a great DB but there are not a lot of tools around it to help build in an agile way.  I know many Informix shops that only use the GeneXus IDE to build web apps and smart phone apps.  If you have not heard of GeneXus, check it out.